# SFINAE overload choice for has or has not operator<<?

Tags: c++, c++11, operators, sfinae, enable-if

Consider these two functions:

```
template <class Type, 
          class = typename std::enable_if</*HAS OPERATOR <<*/>::type>
void f(std::ostream& stream, const Type& value);

template <class Type, 
          class... DummyTypes,
          class = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(DummyTypes) == 0>::type>
void f(std::ostream& stream, const Type& value, DummyTypes...);
```

As the non-variadic overload has the priority over the variadic overload, I want to check whether the type has the `operator<<` with an `std::ostream` using `std::enable_if` in the first version.

So what should I write instead of `/*HAS OPERATOR <<*/` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write a C++ template to check for a function's existence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

Comment: Specifically, check my answer in the dupe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work

```
template <class Type, 
          class = decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<Type>())>
void f(std::ostream& stream, const Type& value)
{
    stream << value;
}
```

(note you don't need to use `std::enable_if` in this case)

Answer (score 6):

Using trailing return type (1), you can actually have a foretaste of concepts:

```
template <typename Type>
auto f(std::ostream& out, Type const& t) -> decltype(out << t, void()) {
    // ...
}
```

Because of SFINAE, this overload can only be selected if the type of `out << t` can be resolved, and this implies that an overload of `<<` exists that accepts both parameters.

The one pitfall is that this does not work if you need *the contrary*, that is enabling a function if this overload *does not exists*. In this case an `enable_if` strategy (and the symmetric `disable_if`) is necessary, as far as I know.

(1) thanks to Simple for helping out with the syntax

Answer (score 2):

It is easiest to check when you have the arguments around, i.e., I would rather try to use something like this:

```
template <typename Type>
auto f(std::ostream& out, Type const& value)
    -> typename std::enable_if<sizeof(out << value) != 0>::type {
    ...
}
```

A similar effect could be obtained using `std::declval()` but off-hand I'm not sure about creating references.

Comment: `sizeof(decltype(...))` is not needed, you can use `sizeof(...)` on an expression directly.

Comment: It is a real pain that one cannot use `void` in regular expressions. `decltype(out << value, void{})` would be so much easier.

Comment: @Simple: Ah! I did not thought about that way of expressing it. That's cool :)

Comment: @DanielFrey: true (fixed the decleration). Thanks.

Comment: There is one more problem in your code, you need `sizeof(out<<value)!=0` as opposed to just `sizeof(out<<value)` because narrowing to bool is not allowed in this context. GCC accepts the broken code, but Clang rejects it.